# Failed to add navigation dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am trying to Add Navigation in my project but its showing failed to add Navigation dependency,

when i click on 'ok' in the window to add these now , its showing failed to add dependency  and my navigation xml editor is not visible

here are some screen shots [image]

my build.gradle (app) :-

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.choudhary.myshop"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

buildFeatures{
    viewBinding = true
}




}

dependencies {




implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'


def lifecycle_version = "2.5.0-alpha01"
def arch_version = "2.1.0"

// ViewModel
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
// ViewModel utilities for Compose
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")
// LiveData
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")

def nav_version = "2.4.0"



// Kotlin
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

// Feature module Support
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version")

// Testing Navigation
androidTestImplementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version")

// Jetpack Compose Integration
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0-alpha01")
}
```

my build.gradle (project ) :-

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please share the updated code. This will help us. I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delete all navigation dependency related , and add this :

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```

Comment: issue solved .may i know the reason .why it happen to me

Comment: personally most of the time I don't get the gradle build syntax error reasons , I just know it works this way

Answer (score 5):

Seems like Navigation with version `2.3.6 - 2.4.*` shows that problem

You can change only

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `2.3.4` instead of `2.3.5/2.5.3`

It's working...

[image: Proof]

Answer (score 0):

The message that I got was a bit more helpful

```
Corrupt serialized resolution result. Cannot find selected module (490)
for constraint releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication -> 
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.6.1
```

So I updated the following dependencies from 2.6.0 to 2.6.1 and it worked

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
```